# How to clear console line using `print` function

Tags: python, console, urwid

## Premise

I'm trying to basically clear the console line, but not the entire console window without using whitespace, so that I don't have extra characters from what was last printed. For example:

```
# This causes characters from the last thing printed:
print("I don't know you.", end="\r")
print("Hello Jim!", end="\r")

# Yields the following (without the quotations) -->
# "Hello Jim!ow you."
```

Now to solve this one can do this:

```py
import os

def new_print(message, end):
    """
    Clears console, no matter the size of the previous line 
    without wrapping to a new line
    """
    width_of_console = int(os.popen("stty size", "r").read().split()[1])
    # = 17

    print(f"{message :<{width_of_console}}", end=end)

new_print("I don't know you.", end="\r")
new_print("Hello Jim!", end="\r")
# Yields the following (without the quotations) -->
# "Hello Jim!       "
```

## Question

How do I

1. *Just* print out `"Hello Jim!"` and not `"Hello Jim!       "` (both obviously without quotations)
2. Clear that line
3. While not clearing the entire console (so that I have the output of other things besides the last line)

Specifically things like this occur in the console when shifting sizes (from say a console width of 17 to 30), which in my case, happens quite often:

```
Hello Jim!       Hello Jim!   
    Hello Jim!       Hello Jim
!       Hello Jim!       Hello
 Jim!       Hello Jim!       H
ello Jim!       Hello Jim!
```

I'm open to an entire new way of doing things, like using [urwid](http://urwid.org/) or something of that nature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the EL (Erase Line) [control sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences). In Python, the easiest way to construct it is:

```
"\033[2K"
```

The number controls the behaviour of the EL sequence:

- 0: clear forward till end of line (default)
- 1: clear backward till beginning of line
- 2: clear whole line

EL sequence does not move the cursor.

This behaviour is rather standard, but if you want to be sure, you can query the terminfo database using `tput`.

tl;dr:

```
print("I don't know you.", end="\r")
print("\033[2KHello Jim!", end="\r")
```

Comment: Adding `end="\r"` in the second print statement shows nothing on my terminal. I think it should be: `print("\033[2KHfasgesgwg", end="")`. Is the behaviour of `\r` terminal specific?

Comment: That was OP's original code, I assumed there was a reason they were going to continue printing on the same line. If you just execute that in a terminal though, the prompt will typically overwrite what you had before.

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you. And to clarify, yes, I'd be printing on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. For better visibility I have added a sleep time.

```
import time


def myprint(msg):
    print(msg, end='', flush=True)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\r', end='', flush=True)
    print(' ' * len(msg), end='', flush=True)
    print('\r', end='', flush=True)


print('These are some other lines 1')
print('These are some other lines 2')

for i in range(10):
    myprint('Hello Jim {}!'.format(i))
```